# Define Point with 2 constraints in Geogebra

Tags: math-software

[image: Geogebra screen]

Hello,
I'm struggling making the model of the "triangle of speeds" (crosswind modelisation in aeronautics) in Geogebra.

What I want to do is simple: **How to define the point B as being the translation of the red vector of the top starting from point A AND as also being on the line (OD)?** (Point A is defined as being on the circle.)

I struggle in geogebra anytime I want to define something with more than one condition.

**How to achieve this result in Geogebra?**

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to extend vector V_W until it hits OD?

If so, then draw Line[A,B] and intersect it with OD.

BTW you will get (much) faster answers about using GeoGebra in this forum:
http://forum.geogebra.org